# AngularJS-Twig conflict with double curly braces

Tags: angularjs, twig

As you know, both angular and twig has common control construction - double curly braces. How can I change default value of Angular?

I know that I can do it in Twig, but in some projects I can't, only JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS custom delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923521/angular-js-custom-delimiter)

Comment: Another twig-specific solution for moustache madness is to use the `verbatim` tag; e.g:`{% verbatim %}{{ angular_var }}{% endverbatim %}` to preserve your moustaches for AngularJS: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html

Comment: Not to author of question, but future readers: if you are looking for answer to this question, consider to avoid templates rendering on server side at all, if you can afford it (if your main content is inside authenticated zone or you main search engine as source of traffic is Google (they can parse JS SPA)).

Comment: @OZ_ The search engine argument against AngularJS and the like becomes quite redundant when using services like [prerender.io](http://prerender.io).

Answer (score 288, accepted):

You can change the start and end interpolation tags using `interpolateProvider` service. One convenient place for this is at the module initialization time.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

Comment: I wouldn't use [[]], though. It could be bad in some bindings, like this one: `[[myObject[myArray[index]]`

Comment: True. I use `{[{}]}` with Django although it is a little odd to type. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Ran into a similar issue with Jeykll / Liquid and Angular JS. I opted for {[ and ]}.

Comment: Doesn't the semicolon need removed after the } on line 3?

Comment: Is there any way to do this on a global level in Angular? Our website will have many, many modules on many different pages, and we don't want to forget to do this.

Comment: Hi, It was just a doubt in mind, and I searched for this question, This is great solution, But Why can not we just use "ng-bind" instead

Comment: Since twig is the pre-processor that gets activated first when `{{something}}` is read, wouldn't it make more sense to adjust the settings of twig rather than angular? Are there alternatives to `{` curly braces in twig? It would be nice to keep angular as is, and modify the preprocessor.

Answer (score 91):

This question appears answered, but a more elegant solution that hasn't been mentioned is to simply enclose the curly braces in quote marks between the twig curly braces, like so:

```
{{ '{{myModelName}}' }}
```

If you are using a variable for the contents, do this instead:

```
{{ '{{' ~ yourvariable ~ '}}' }}
```

You should use **single quotes**, not double quotes. Double quotes enable string interpolation by Twig so you have to be more careful with the contents, especially if you are using expressions.

---

If you still hate seeing all those curly braces, you can also create a simple macro to automate the process:

```
{% macro curly(contents) %}
   {{ '{{' ~ contents ~ '}}' }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Save it as a file and import it into your template. I am using `ng` for the name because it is short and sweet.

```
{% import "forms.html" as ng %}
```

Or you can put the macro at the top of your template and import it as _self [(see here)](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#macros):

```
{% import _self as ng %}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
{{ ng.curly('myModelName') }}
```

This outputs:

```
{{myModelName}}
```

---

...and a follow up for those that use [MtHaml](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml) alongside Twig. MtHaml enables the use of AngularJS curlies in the normal manner because any Twig code is accessed though - and = instead of {{ }}. For example:

Plain HTML + AngularJS:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
   <td> {{ product.name }} </td>
</tr>
```

MtHaml + AngularJS:

```
%tr(ng-repeat="product in products")
   %td {{ product.name }}
```

MtHaml + AngularJS with MtHaml-style Twig:

```
- set twigVariable = "somevalue"
= twigVariable
%tr(ng-repeat="product in products")
   %td {{ product.name }}
```

Comment: It's maybe not the most pleasant way, but I my opinion it's the only way to don't worry about compatibility issue. Ether modify Angular or Twig {{ could create compatibility issue or bad portability.

Comment: The solution provided only started to work for me when I did this

`{{'{{contact.name}\}'}}`

which prints `{{contact.name}}` as I wanted

Answer (score 37):

As mentioned in similar question about Django and AngularJS, trick with changing default symbols (in Twig or AngularJS) can provide incompatibility with third-party software, which will use these symbols.
So best advice I found in google: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/symfony2/kyebufz4M00/8VhF1KWsSAEJ

> TwigBundle does not provide a configuration for the lexer delimiters
>   as changing them would forbid you to use any templates provided by
>   shared bundles (including the exception templates provided by
>   TwigBundle itself).
>
> However, you could use the raw tag around your angular templates to
>   avoid the pain of escaping all curly braces:
>   http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/raw.html
>   --  Christophe | Stof

Tag was renamed to [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html)

Comment: Please note that the raw tag has been renamed to "verbatim" due to avoid confusion with the raw filter of twig.

Comment: This is in my opinion the cleanest way.

Answer (score 27):

You can use too the attribute-based directive `<p ng-bind="yourText"></p>` is the same as `<p>{{yourText}}</p>`

Comment: This must be the better solution actually.

Comment: how to use it on attr,like `<li id={{item.id}}></li>` ?

Comment: Even better would be using `<p data-ng-bind="yourText"></p>` to make the HTML valid

Answer (score 23):

You can use `\{{product.name}}` to get the expression ignored by Handlebars and used by Angular instead.

Comment: Good solution - simply escape the reserved characters, also works in Handlebars

Answer (score 23):

This is a compiled version of the best answers and a example for verbatim blocks:

For single insertions, use:

```
{{ '{{model}}' }}
```

or if you use a twig variable

```
{{ '{{' ~ twigVariableWitModelName ~ '}}' }}
```

[Verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html), is very elegant and readable for several angular variables:

```
<table ng-table>
    {% verbatim %}
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td data-title="'Name'">{{user.name}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Age'">{{user.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endverbatim %}
</table>
```

Comment: Ah , this was the life-saver for me . I couldnt use {{param}} inside Filter: { {{param}} : $select.search} and your solution fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

If you're not interested in changing the template tags of the existing angular syntax which would require some confusing rewriting of your existing angular templates.

One can just use the twig template tags with angular tags like so:

```
{% verbatim %}{{yourName}}{% endverbatim %}
```

Found this on another similar thread [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11478993/171217): [Angularjs on a symfony2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834390/angularjs-on-a-symfony2-application)

Comment: @ThomasReggi The OP is asking for a solution for Twig. Check out the other answers that can also work for Liquid.

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively you can change the characters used by Twig. This is controlled by the [Twig_Lexer](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Lexer.php).

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment();

$lexer = new Twig_Lexer($twig, array(
    'tag_comment'   => array('[#', '#]'),
    'tag_block'     => array('[%', '%]'),
    'tag_variable'  => array('[[', ']]'),
    'interpolation' => array('#[', ']'),
));
$twig->setLexer($lexer);
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

According to [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.symfony.symfony2/7858) you should be able to do it like this :

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
  }]);
```

Comment: where should I put these codes? | oh! I got it, I have to make ng-app=app

Comment: Just starting with AngularJS and within Laravel 4 I loaded the framework and then added {{2+2}} to the view - nothing else at all and it evaluated to 4. Where do I put the code to change this to [[2+2]]? I've tried adding it between script tags on the same page and adding ng-app="myApp" to the containing div tag but it doesn't work.

Comment: It need to be placed in your javascript, same place controllers are defined. For a working example, look at the documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolateProvider) in the script.js tab.

Comment: A word of caution, I was using the double square brackets for Angular, but I just ran into a problem with the Django Message framework. Messages creates a cookie that contains [[ ]] and Angular tries to parse it and chokes in the process. I've tried switching to session storage for messages, but same issue. I switched to triple square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I like @pabloRN, but I would prefer to use span instead of p, because for me p will add line to the result.

I will use this:

```
<span ng-bind="yourName"></span>
```

I also use aText with the cursor inside the double quote so I don't have to rewrite the whole thing over and over again.

Comment: actually ng-bind="" is what matters, you can use any tag you like :)

Comment: @wesamly You can use any tag, but `<span>` is used for inline text when you have other content. For instance: `<h1>Welcome <span ng-bind="yourName"></span></h1>`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in twig to surround your angular directives, so like instead of going ...

`{{"angular"}}`

you go ...

`{{angular_parser("angular stuff here output curlies around it")}}`

Comment: Please user code blocks in for code snippet in your answers.