# Symfony2 validate form in Angular js

Tags: symfony, angularjs

I am trying to use anular js with symfony2, but i am struggling which integrating Angular to Symfony2

I have following form class in symfony2

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
     $builder
     ->add('name','text')
     ->add('address','textarea',array('required'=>false))
     ->add('city','text')
     ->add('state','text',array('required'=>false))
}
```

I am rendering form in twing, following is the code

```
<form action="{{ path('customer_create') }}" method="post" name="form1" ng-controller="MainCtrl" {{ form_enctype(form) }} >
    {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
    <div>{{ form_label(form.name) }} {{ form_widget(form.name) }}</div>
    <div>{{ form_label(form.email) }} {{ form_widget(form.email) }}</div>
    <div>{{ form_label(form.address) }} {{ form_widget(form.address) }}</div>
    <div>{{ form_label(form.city) }} {{ form_widget(form.city) }}</div>
    <br><br><br> <button type="submit" style="float:left;text-align:left;margin-right:10px">{% trans %}Create{% endtrans %}</button>
</form>
```

How can i use Angular js in it?

Comment: You can use angular as you would with a static html page. Look at the HTML output of the form and adjust angular as you need.

Comment: If you're generating forms on the server side when using AngularJS, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Sgoettschkes: i have checked the same in html and its working in pure html too

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Angular JS `{{` and `}}` with something else

check [AngularJS-Twig conflict with double curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces) for details

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the follow:

twig: (im using boostrap)

```
 <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        {{ form_label(form.tipomoneda, 'Tipo Moneda') }}
        {{ form_widget(form.tipomoneda,{'attr': {'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Introducir tipo de moneda', 'ng-model':'tipomoneda' }}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.tipomoneda) }}
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="{{ form.vars.name }}['{{ form.vars.name }}[{{ form.tipomoneda.vars.name }}]'].$dirty && {{ form.vars.name }}['{{ form.vars.name }}[{{ form.tipomoneda.vars.name }}]'].$invalid">
        <span ng-show="{{ form.vars.name }}['{{ form.vars.name }}[{{ form.tipomoneda.vars.name }}]'].$error.required">Field  required.</span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

where:

```
    <form name= "moneda" ...  will be = {{ form.vars.name }}
 <input type="text" name="moneda[tipomoneda]" ...  will be = {{ form.tipomoneda.vars.name }}
```

so the solution is to use Javascript's property style accessors for objects (square brackets) over the dot object notation.. Thus we can have the square brackets in a string and there is no evaluation issue.