# Slim template interprets {{myJsVar}} as HTML attribute grouping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, slim-lang

I'm playing around with Angularjs and Slim but am trying to figure out how to come up with a cleaner syntax.

I want to do:

```
td {{content.name}}
td {{content.body}}
td {{content.owner}}
```

But it gives me an error.  Most likely because `{` is used to group HTML attributes.  I've had to change it to this:

```
td
  | {{content.name}}
td
  | {{content.body}}
td
  | {{content.owner}}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13671817/586621). You can change the interpolation tags that AngularJS uses.

Comment: Hmm, that would still be a problem because slim would treat it as:
`<td {content.name=></td>`

I think a better option would be to modify slim so that it didn't use `{` for html attribute grouping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change that allows this is in slim version 2.0.3.

You can add the following in `config/initializers/slim.rb`:

```
Slim::Engine.set_options :attr_list_delims => {'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}
```

This removes `{` from the defaults. See [the doc here](https://github.com/slim-template/slim) and search on the page for `attr_list_delims`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you'd consider it cleaner but you can put all the attributes in parentheses.

```
td() {{content.name}}
td(otherattr=2 thisattr=3) {{content.body}}
td() {{content.owner}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up patching the Slim gem itself.  Only 2 lines changed.

You can see it at https://github.com/brennancheung/slim/tree/angularjs_support

And can include it in your Rails project using:

```
gem 'slim', :git => 'git://github.com/brennancheung/slim.git', :branch => 'angularjs_support'
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this. I'm using PadrinoRB and BackboneJS and was running into the same "problem". I had it working the same way you did at first, but this is definitely much cleaner.

Comment: i worry about this not being maintained... with future iterations of slim

Comment: Do you mind sharing which lines were change in your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @gwho The change is simple but it took me some time to find.  You can check the last commit in my fork to see the changes (https://github.com/brennancheung/slim/commit/53dec2403bde08b1959226212864f78015ce273f).  I'm mostly using Node.js these days so I'm not planning on maintaining it but it should be pretty easy for anyone else to take over.  I originally tried to add a config option, so that it would be easy to merge the pull request in without breaking compatibility, but it looked like a lot more work and would require some re-architecting.  :(

Comment: I'd suggest to update the answer since the fix was merged https://github.com/slim-template/slim/pull/434 . The config option is: `Slim::Engine.set_default_options :attr_delims => {'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}`

Comment: Thanks @VladimirChervanev for pointing me in the right direction. I added a full answer with updated instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but there is a perfect solution now. The latest slim supports custom `attr_delims` options. I don't know when it was added, but v2.0.3 has that. With command line, you can use:

`slimrb -o "attr_delims={'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}" <file>`

Or if you use `gulp-slim`, you can write it like this:

```
.pipe(slim({
  pretty: true,
  options: "attr_delims={'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}"
}))
```

You can refer to the doc [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-slim).

Answer (score 0):

On other variant, but I'm still not happy with it, is to do:

```
td ng-bind="content.name"
td ng-bind="content.body"
td ng-bind="content.owner"
```

I'm leaning towards customizing slim so that it doesn't use `{` for grouping HTML attributes.