# Remove handlebars package from meteor app

Tags: node.js, meteor, handlebars.js

I need to use angularjs for my client side framework on my meteor application, so I won't be using handlebars. Is there a way to remove the package?

And if it's not possible, can handlebars work correctly side-by-side with angularjs?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [meteor-angular-stack](https://github.com/bramtervoort/meteor-angular-stack) or [ng-meteor](https://github.com/olanod/ng-meteor). Should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the Angular's delimiters. I don't know how to do so with meteor instead, they are not implementing the [Mustache default way to change delimiters](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#set-delimiter).

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

[AngularJS-Twig conflict with double curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces)