# Load the application with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, variables, symfony

I'm having some problems loading a simple AngularJS with symfony app.

Here is my `index.html.twig`:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}


{% block body %}
    <div ng-app>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">

      <hr>
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts output='js/main.js' debug=false
    'bundles/acmesqltest/js/angular.min.js' -%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

When i see the source code on the browser and click the `angular.min.js` reference.. all the code is there.

[image]

But, if i add, next to the `input` `{{yourName}}`, symfony says the variable does not exist.

[image]

Is there any other configuration that i need to do ?

Comment: You're probably running into a problem with {{}} being used in some other templating (within symphony I would guess)  You can change the characters angular looks for for $interpolate to avoid the issue but even better you should write your service as a RESTful back-end that communicates with the front end via JSON request/response since this is decoupled and what is expected by angular's services ($http or $resource).

Comment: Perfect! Also, I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces and it solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: No problem glad you were able to get it sorted.