# Alternative Delimiters for Handlebars

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, handlebars.js, mustache

I read on the handlebars js website that...

> Alternative delimeters are not supported.

... and unfortunately it conflicts with Angular JS. I want to do something like what I can do in handlebars...

**.json**

```
{
  "people": [{"name":"joe"}, {"name":"jay"}, {"name":"jim"}]
}
```

**.tpl.html**

```
{{={% %}=}}

{%#people%}
   <li>{%name%}: {{localtime('{%name%}')}}</li>
{%/people%}
```

And end up with...

```
<li>joe: {{localtime('joe')}}</li>
<li>jay: {{localtime('jay')}}</li>
<li>jim: {{localtime('jim')}}</li>
```

... which is ready for angular js to process.

I do not want to alter angular js delimiters, I use them much more heavily throughout the app. The best I can come up with, is to parse the HTML, and replace angular delimiters with a unique token, then swap instances of `{%` and `%}` with `{{` and `}}`, process with handlebars, and then replace the tokens with original angular delimiters again on the processed output.

This seems like far too much work. Is there another alternative?

I am using grunt, is there a plugin to do what I am trying to do here?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces

Comment: Why are you using *both* handlebars and Angular templates?

Comment: I want to use handlebars during the build process, and angular on the client side.