# slim with angular - Conflict using {{double curly braces}}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, slim-lang

When you use `{{}}`, slim looks at the first `{` and thinks it's an attribute.

How can you disable `{` as a key character from slim. so that using `{{ }}` will be interpreted as angular, not a slim attribute?

(P.S. I'm using `slim-rails` gem, so the solution may be specific to rails, but who knows?)

Comment: You can use ng-bind or https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Comment: While a valid solution, that would probably be extremely tedious and annoying to code/read/maintain. I can already use `|` or `'` in front of the `{{}}` as provided by slim, parsing it as raw text, which gets interpreted as angular

Comment: I don't know about slim, but you can change the interpolation markers (`{{`, `}}`) in Angular. E.g. instead of `{{ ... }}` use `[[ ... ]]` or `(-: ... :-)` or whatever :)

Comment: Would I need to change it in angular with a setting, or do you mean that I can just use those syntax?

Comment: In this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces , the accepted answer shows how to change waht angular considers `{{}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what I do without changing settings:

```
p
  | {{ user.name }}
  = a_method_call
```

or

```
p ng-bind="user.name" = a_method_call
```

Comment: would you know how to change the settings? =D

Comment: Also, with your way, how do you handle content that has more stuff after it that is not verbatim text?

e.g. `p | {{user.name}} a_method_call`

Comment: edited for method call, do you really feel like it worth it to change angular's config?

Comment: I'd rather change slim's config, since slim has multiple syntax: `{}` `[]` `()`. Telling slim to stop recognizing `{}` would allow angular to be as is, leaving you with two other options for slim. I found how to adjust angular settings here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces

Comment: ok look here: https://github.com/slim-template/slim#available-options, even if I dont feel like it worth it :)

Comment: The missing info is WHERE to put those config settings (why do people assume people know where to place everything? xp). I also happen to be using slim-rails, which doesn't generate a config/initializer file. I guess it's not worth it.

Comment: Oh, I can just create a file from scratch? Would slim-rails recognize it? Most likely, since it uses slim... I guess I can install slim, see what the initializer file wrappers look like, copy that, uninstall slim, create my initializer from scratch, and put in the code I wish within the wrappers.

Comment: Very good to know. I am using `slim-rails`, so I meant I'd keep `slim-rails`, but install then uninstall `slim` just to see what the proper config code would require.

Answer (score 4):

You can change default options of slim, to not use { }. Put it to initializers folder:

```
Slim::Engine.set_options attr_list_delims: {'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}, code_attr_delims: {'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's really inconvenient to have to separate text onto a new line with the pile (|) and get the rails syntax to work.  This is really the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to change the interpolation markers in Angular, you can use the corresonding methods of the **[`$interpolateProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider)** inside a config block:

```
angular.
    module('myApp', []).
    config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    });
```

Then Angular will not recognize the old markers (`{{`, `}}`).
You'll be using the new ones:

```
<span>[[someValue]]</span>
```

Comment: unfortunately, slim detects all three of `{}` `[]` and `()`, so wouldn't any alternative angular symbol starting with any of these three characters still have the same problem? You'd need to use a different character?

Comment: @gwho: You can use any character sequence (and of any length) that suits you. I am not familiar with slim, so I can;t make a good suggestion.