# displaying angularjs model data when using jekyll and liquid?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jekyll, liquid

I'm using jekyll with liquid for my website. I want to use angularjs to read json and parse the data on the html page. but both liquid and angularjs use {{}}. So when i try to display angularjs data, it won't because liquid thinks it's a variable created by jekyll. How can i use both jekyll and angularjs? or is there a better approach?

Comment: nevermind, i found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13671817/3893181

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS-Twig conflict with double curly braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces)

Answer (score 3):

This question is kinda old now but I found a better solution than the one proposed in the linked SO question. The best way to use AngularJS with Jekyll is to use the `raw` tags like so:

```
{% raw %}
  \\ All the Angular goodness goes here...
{% endraw %}
```