# Use an Angular JS value as a parameter of TWIG "path" function in Symfony 2

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

The `{[{project.id}]}` AngularJS variable is not interpreted by twig in the **path function**. This my code:

```
<section class="main" ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{% trans %}Id{% endtrans %}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="project in filteredProjectList">
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ path('project_show', { 'projectId': {[{project.id}]} }) }}">
                        {[{ project.id }]}
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <pagination
            total-items="totalItems" 
            items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
            ng-model="currentPage" 
            ng-change="pageChanged()">
    </pagination>
</section> 

<script>
    angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap').config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
    });
</script>
```

Have you got a trick to fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is client-side, twig is server-side, so you cannot call twig's `path` function from angular.

If you want to generate routes on the client, look into [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).

Comment: @Maerlyn could you please post solution example for problem mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, but you don't need to interpolate `product.id` again.  This should be ok, but it would help to see your `path` function:

```
<tr ng-repeat="project in filteredProjectList">
    <td>
        <a ng-click="path('project_show', { 'projectId': project.id })">
            {[{ project.id }]}
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm assuming here that `path` is a function defined on the controller's `$scope`.

Comment: It's not "my" path function, but it's a Symfony 2 function, see the documentation here : http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/templating.html#linking-to-pages
Thx for the help anyway