# Python Flask + Angular Error: 'StoreController Undefined'

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

I have three files in my python flask application built on angular js for front end.

**app.py**

```
    import json
    import flask
    import numpy as np


    app = flask.Flask(__name__)


    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        return flask.render_template("index.html")


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import os

        port = 80

        # Open a web browser pointing at the app.
        os.system("open http://localhost:{0}".format(port))

        # Set up the development server on port 80.
        app.debug = True
        app.run(port=port)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="gemStore">
      <head>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/app.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
            <div class="list-group-item">
                   <h3>{{store.product.name}} <em class="pull-right">25</em></h3>
            </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
      var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

      app.controller('StoreController', function(){
                  this.product = gem;
              }
      );


      var gem =  {
                      name: "Chicken",
                      price: 123.11,
                      color: "White"
                  };

    })();
```

When I run this application, the presence of the following line causes an error:

```
<h3>{{store.product.name}} <em class="pull-right">25</em></h3>
```

I get an error saying.
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
UndefinedError: 'store' is undefined

This is strange because the same front end application would run properly if I didn't use a python flask server.
Also, I checked the html file is correctly referencing the app.js file by testing an alert.

Comment: `flask.render_template("index.html")` you need to pass the argument too

Comment: for store.product.name that you using in template

Comment: I am new to flask and angular. Can you please explicitly tell me which line in which file needs to be changed from what to what?
If you do that, please publish it as an answer. Will help others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

The answer is here:
[AngularJS-Twig conflict with double curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces)

**Modified app.js to**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

 app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
 }); // NEWLY ADDED

  app.controller('StoreController', function(){
              this.product = gem;
          }
  );


  var gem =
              {
                  name: "Chicken",
                  price: 123.11,
                  color: "White"
              }
  ;

})();
```

**Modified index.html to:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
        <div class="list-group-item">
               <h3>{[{store.product.name}]} <em class="pull-right">25</em></h3>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Flask uses Jinja2 to render HTML template, which like AngularJS, uses {{ + }} denote variables being passed through via `render_template`.

In this particular case, you're trying to access `store.product.name` which is a variable from within AngularJS. However, because Jinja2 (i.e. Flask) processes the HTML first it tries to treat it as a Flask variable being passed to the template renderer.

If you want the HTML to print out with `{{store.product.name}}` to be a variable parsed by AngularJS, you'll need to tell Jinja2 that: "Hey, I don't want you to parse this as a Flask variable."

There are a few different ways of doing that.

First, you can add the `{{` `}}`` as escaped text:

```
<h3>{{ '{{' }}store.product.name{{ '}}' }} <em class="pull-right">25</em></h3>
```

This will add {{ and }} around the string `store.product.name` and be rendered as `{{store.product.name}}`

Alternatively, you can write a Jinja2 Filter that tells it to not parse the variable and return the raw-string. For example, Flask-Triangle is a Flask extension that includes an angularjs filter:

http://flask-triangle.readthedocs.org/en/develop/tutorial/part1.html

however one can be easily written yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This is super helpful.
However, when I tried importing flask.ext.triangle I got an error that it doesn't exist:
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.triangle

I can't find any resources to download triangle.

Comment: You can install it either via pip or manually downloading it. See the [installation](http://flask-triangle.readthedocs.org/en/develop/installing.html) instructions on flask-triangle's docs website.

Comment: This package is different from the one you shared. They are named same and do similar things but documentation differs for this:
http://flask-triangle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/glance.html#the-angular-filter

For this package, flask.ext.triangle exists but flask.ext.triangle.Triangle does not exist.
The way include angular tags for this package is very verbose and affects the simplicity of the view.