# Creating a Website with Polymer and Twig

Tags: twig, polymer

I am a not-so-newbie Web Developer. I can write websites using HTML5, CSS3, JS, and PHP.
Now I am working on a school project but I am very much unsure how I will proceed.

I want to use Material Design on my project, so I came across  Google's [Material Design Lite](http://www.getmdl.io/).
It was good. But was inadequate for my project (which is a responsive website). So I came across with the new [Polymer 1.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) and saw the Paper Elements components with it which offers more components that I need.

So here's what I'm unsure about.
Can I use Polymer Elements with Twig?
I know about the issue with the data binding markup in Polymer being the same as the output tag in Twig ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces)) and its not bothering me anymore. My problem is, will it be recommended to use Polymer and Twig? I'm unsure because I saw an article about Twig being *"dead"* because of web components. And for me it implies that the two have the same use cases and I will not be able to use it both. Is that right?

**[Edit Start]**
I saw that Polymer (or web components to be exact) are much like templates in a way (as I'm reading tons of things earlier but forgot where). So will I have problems because I'm using Symfony?
**[Edit End]**

I'm also interested with Polymer's Elements **only** and I think (for now) that I  will not be creating my own components. Also, I'm using Twig with Symfony (if that information will help). I'm seriously stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, Polymer is not supposed to serve as a front-end template engine. It is a library/framework by itself, and its components are designed to receieve data from backend via AJAX calls. You can code backend for Polymer at PHP, but I don't see a place for Twig in this scheme, unless you want to pass blocks of HTML code via AJAX from your backend to Polymer, which is against Polymer ideology.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm a newbie when I posted this question and I have learned many things after a year. Also, I'm a bit experimenting with things at that time so I really am doing wrong things. Lastly, Polymer now have grown into a nice framework compared to when it is released (for me) so things became obvious now (for me). Still, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I was roaming the web for similar topic and didn't look at the question date. Thank you for accepting my answer.