# Transform jsx.twig to js.twig

Tags: symfony, reactjs, twig

I am using Symfony2 Framework. For view part, I am using Reactjs. Since, twig also uses '{{' and '}}', So to use '{{' in twig , I am doing following:

```
<div {{'dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.html}}'}}></div>
```

and

```
<div style={{'{{width:10}}'}}
```

When I try to transform this jsx into js, I get error wherever I have used braces for twig. How to transform a jsx code having twig variables and twig braces into JS?

EDIT:
here is the [twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/0s0xpr/3) . If I try to transform this code to js using JSX compiler , then I get error: Error: Parse Error: Line 4: Unexpected token %

Comment: have you already see the [verbatim tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html)?

Comment: Even if I use verbatim, then Error will be shown for {%verbatim%} . The transformer will give unexpected token error as soon as it will see '{%'

Comment: sorry i don't understand the problem... check if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces/13671817#13671817

Comment: SOrry for bad english. I want to transform JSX to JS. and because of use of twig, The transformer is unable to change jsx to js. So I want some work around

Comment: i don't understand the problem because i don't know more about reactjs and jsx! :)

Comment: ca you replicate the problem in a [twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/)?

Comment: [twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/0s0xpr)

If I try to transform this code to js using [JSX compiler](https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html) , then I get error: 

Error: Parse Error: Line 4: Unexpected token %