# AngularJS - Catch part of code rendered by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm having trouble with catching scope `[[gallery]]` which one MUST rendered by php because plugin is creating popup by XHR request.

```
<html>
<body ng-app="app">
      here are all scopes (displaying data)
   -- here's part rendered by PHP and sended to view but it shows as [[scope]]
</body>
</html>
```

How can "resume" angular to catch scope after rendering it by php?

Comment: Please explain in far more detail. As it stands right now this is not understandable

Comment: I would like to escape [[ ]] rendered by php to allow angular for use it. I'm using smarty. {literal} does not work. Even using directives does not work when i render part of code by php.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces