# What are the best practices for Twig + Angular? (view syntax)

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

Want to know if there's some best practices around the use of both together.

There's a conflict with the use of {{ }} for example.

People talk about interpolate:

```js
angular.module('app', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

Is it the best way? Are there more tips on other use cases?

Thanks you guys!

Comment: Hi,
I don't know of any best practices but at my company we are using the "standard" syntax it's a bit ugly but with code-highlighting it works fine.
<a href="{{ '{{ myVar }}' }}">

Comment: Hmm didn't know it works, sounds good! Thanks for the comment

Comment: Your solution is the way to go @RodrigoQuiñonesPichioli. Use whatever symbol suits to you.
Just my 2 cents : Mixing client-side and server-side templating may be a bad practice. So I would choose one of the two.
For example, if you are building a rich web application, use Angular template mechanisms and use only Twig ones for specific cases.
This way you could maybe keep the origin AngularJS interpolation symbols.

Comment: I understand and agree with you on your explanation, it really depends on the purpose and architecture of each project. Thanks for the comment @Neozaru, I appreciate that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS-Twig conflict with double curly braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces)

Comment: use symfony as a backend and angular as a front end... they should be seperated

Comment: I'm talking about practices, I just mentioned the interpolation as an example @Dam Dufel

Comment: Ok, that's a good point @NDM, thanks for the explanation