# twig date filter not working (angular issue?)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony, twig

I'm passing a DateTime object from php to twig, and when calling it on my twig:

```
{% verbatim %} {{ user.updatedAt }} {% endverbatim %}
```

I'm getting this output on my page:

```
{"date":"2017-02-08 18:53:22.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe/Lisbon"}
```

When I try to apply the filter `date("H:i")` on this variable, it's not applied and I get this on the page:

```
{{ user.updatedAt|date("H:i") }}
```

In this case, I also have the following angularjs error in the console, which I think is related:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '(' is an unexpected token at column 24 of the expression [ user.updatedAt|date("H:i") ] starting at [("H:i") ].
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Comment: Hi, without considering the fact the date you are passing is not a javascript date you call the filter in the wrong way. Take a look here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Hi rick, I'm trying to call the twig date filter, not the angularjs one. Is there a conflict with these filters? How should I do it? Thanks

Comment: ok sorry, it seams a pretty common problem, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Twig to parse your line and process the date filter, you have to remove the "{% verbatim %}" tags. They are used to explicitly tell Twig that the content of the block is ***NOT*** to be parsed.

Your current code is indeed outputting data that is parsed by Angular since the double curly braces are not parsed by Twig, hence your angular parsing exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I honestly thought that that variable was being parsed by twig, but it was in fact parsed by angular. The angular date filter is different from the twig one, hence the error.