# Generate Twig Template from Twig Template? (CodeGenerator)

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, code-generation

I write a code generator in Symfony2 with twig.

My problem is: I want to create a twig template with a twig template.

For a better understanding here an example:
I have a twig file that is a template for a PHP Page - so if i run it it generates me PHP code from that twig template. (ex. a `Controller for CRUD`)

Now I want to generate the view template - but how can i tell twig to use the commands I need for generation and let the dynamic parts for the template as is?

Can I change how the tags are formed? Can I change `{{ varname }}` in `[[ varname ]]` ?

THX for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can!, take the Sensio CRUD generator as an example:

- https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Resources/skeleton/crud/views/index.html.twig.twig
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html

To prevent the rendering of some parts you can:

- Use strings as the SensioGeneratorBundle does.
- Use the verbatim tag to prevent the parsing of some parts (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html)
- Change the syntax as you are suggesting (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax)

You might find the same issue working with AngularJS in Twig templates:

- [AngularJS-Twig conflict with double curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671701/angularjs-twig-conflict-with-double-curly-braces)
- [Angularjs on a symfony2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834390/angularjs-on-a-symfony2-application)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`{% verbatim %}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) tag.

Verbatim let you write Twig code without interpretation, for example:

```
{% verbatim %}
  {% for key, value in array %}
    {{ value }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endverbatim %}
```

Will literally output:

```
  {% for key, value in array %}
    {{ value }}
  {% endfor %}
```