# AngularJS with Symfony and Twig resource not found before page is fully loaded

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

I'm creating an app with AngularJS and Symfony with Twig. When I use ng-repeat like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people">
  <img src="{{ '{{ person.photo }}' }}"/>
</div>
```

in the browsers console I always get error that resource `{{ person.photo }}` not found. I believe it makes the page loading time longer and also it doesn't look good when console is full of errors. How do I solve this?

Comment: dont forget `{% verbatim %}` so twig is not interpreting the lines

Comment: I use additional `{{ '` and `'}}` to display twig variables so I don't need to use `{% verbatim %}`. Anyway checked if that makes any difference, but unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: Some help here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834390/angularjs-on-a-symfony2-application

Answer (score 0):

You can also change default start/end tags in AngularJS like below:

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
```